# Notation Inside the Parentheses of a Function

Tags: functions, notation

Using the standard notation f(x), if x is strictly 1 or 2, how would this be denoted inside the parentheses? I need to use this notation also for 3,4,5, and 6. Eventually I will need to use it for long sequences of numbers where I know the exact beginning point and end point.

The numbers are natural numbers. The order does matter.

Comment: You can use $(f(x))_{x =1}^\infty$ to denote a sequence.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  f(x) for x= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 would be f(1), f(2),  f(3), f(4), f(5), f(6).  Are you asking for a notation for a sequence of values?   Perhaps { f(n) | a< n< b}.

Comment: Yes, for a sequence of values. For example, begin at 7 and end at 22.

Comment: If $f$ is a function of one argument, you should only put one value inside the parentheses at a time, unless you are trying to confuse your Readers.

Comment: $f(x_i), ( i =2,6  ) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard way of denoting restrictions on $x$ inside the parentheses of $f(x)$.  It'd be better to separately state the restrictions.  Examples:

- $f(x)$, where $x \in S$ (where $S$ may be a previously defined set),
- $f(n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
- $f(x)$, where $x \in \{1, 2\}$,
- $f(n)$, where $n$ is an integer and $1 \le n \le 714$,
- $f(x)$, where $x \in \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{714}$.

Comment: I have also seen $f\upharpoonright A$ (that is, f \upharpoonright) and $f|A$ to denote the restriction of the function $f$ to the domain $A$ when $A$ is a subset of the domain of $f$.